# Junit for SFTP over HTTP Proxy

Tags: python, proxy, java, sftp

I have written a python script that connect to SFTP server over HTTP proxy using Paramiko library using nc command.
Now I want to write a Junit Test for the same in java language.
Is any any library that I can use? As I was going through I found that Test Containers can be used for creating a Fake Sftp Server and not sure what can be used to fake proxy server which can be able to connect to this fake sftp server.
Note that I am using JUNIT 5.